# Mysql large import and low cpu usage

Tags: mysql-workbench

i am using Mysql 5.7 with default configuration and I often import large sql dumps (size of dump around 1GB). Import takes too long but resources are not fully used.

In htop and nmon I see following usage:
CPU usage: average 20% of each core
Disk usage: average 20%
Memory usage: 8GB / 32GB

I was tryed import with **mysql --quick** but it is slowly too.

Do somebody know why is my resource usage too low? In time of import I dont need resource for others processes and I want 100% usage only for import.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you still want speed, please consider posting additional information requested. Happy Holidays and Stay Safe.